# No Semantic Prime For Forming A Question?

Tags: semantics, linguistic-universals, questions, natural-semantic-metalanguage

"Huh", or some variant of it, is universal.
http://huh.ideophone.org/

Yet, I see no word for forming a question in the list of semantic primes. There's "when/time", "where/place", but no "huh" or "what".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_primes

Has anyone addressed how to form questions with semantic primes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's because "huh", and some other interjections and formulaics are considered by many linguists to be at a cross-road between body language and spoken/mental language. Thus, even if some interjections or formulaics are universal, many linguists don't consider them to be traditional words.

Ref.:
https://pure.mpg.de/rest/items/item_855720/component/file_855719/content

Comment: Can you please [edit] this to add some quotes or references to NSM researchers showing that this is what they'd say? Something not being a "word" is unlikely to make much of a difference to NSM researchers considering they even extend their theory to cultural scripts.

Comment: @curiousdannii Done.

Comment: Huh............